# Run-time Error '3061' Too few parameters. Expected 8

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create a vba code to append some data to a Table named T_Tickets

Below the code I'm using.

```
Function addticketScheduleChange()
Dim route As String
route = InputBox("Please enter the URL for the ticket:", "Schedule Review")
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim frm As Form
Set frm = Form_Frm_View_Team

sSQL = "Insert INTO T_Tickets ([CSA Login],[Team Manager],[Schedule Description],[WF Shift Pattern],[Mytime Schedule Description],[Shift Pattern Description],[Mytime Description Code],[Type of Ticket],[Resolved?],[Date Submited],[Ticket Link])" _
& "Select " _
& "frm.[CSA Login]" & ", " _
& "frm.[Team Manager]" & ", " _
& "frm.[Schedule Description]" & ", " _
& "frm.[CSSM SPD]" & ", " _
& "frm.[Mytime Descrription]" & ", " _
& "frm.[Shift Pattern Descr]" & ", " _
& "frm.[MytimeDescriptionCode]" & ", " _
& "'Schedule Change'" & ", " _
& False & ", " _
& "Now()" & ", " _
& "route"
db.Execute sSQL
MsgBox ("Record saved.")

End Function
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sSQL = "Insert INTO T_Tickets ([CSA Login],[Team Manager],[Schedule Description],[WF Shift Pattern],[Mytime Schedule Description],[Shift Pattern Description],[Mytime Description Code],[Type of Ticket],[Resolved?],[Date Submited],[Ticket Link]) " _
& "Values (" _
& "'" & frm.[CSA Login] & "'," _
& "'" & frm.[Team Manager] & "'," _
& "'" & frm.[Schedule Description] & "'," _
& "'" & frm.[CSSM SPD] & "'," _
& "'" & frm.[Mytime Descrription] & "'," _
& "'" & frm.[Shift Pattern Descr] & "'," _
& "'" & frm.[MytimeDescriptionCode] & "'," _
& "'Schedule Change'," _
& " False, " _
& " Now(), " _
& "'" & route & "')"
```